# Are men with shoe size 40 more faithful, and shoe size 43+ less faithful?

Tags: sexuality

The following claim has been all over news, at least Russian ones, e.g. [here](http://en.news-original.ru/scientists-faithful-men-depends-on-the-size-of-his-shoes.html) <sub>(pardon the errors - this sounds like an English translation of the Russian text that was in turn translated to English, belying URL's domain name :)</sub>)

> In the course of the research, it was found that men with a Shoe size from 43 and above, not so often loyal to its mate, as men with smaller feet.
>
> Studies conducted by psychologists Illicit Encounters suggests that the probability of cheating in the pair is higher the larger the leg of a young man. At the same time, men 40 Shoe size continues to be the most faithful companions of life.
>
> This relationship was set by observations of the men who go to Dating sites.

Are men with shoe size 40 more faithful, and shoe size 43+ less faithful?

The article sounds like the source is some weak analysis by a dating site "expert", so I'd prefer answers rooted in something a bit more rigorous if available.

Comment: Found another article talking about a similar topic, once again, no sources. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2938859/How-hands-predict-infidelity-People-ring-index-fingers-length-likely-faithful.html

Comment: And another one, as you said in your post, the sources of those claims seems to be "Illicit Encounters", an extra martial dating site
The article : http://metro.co.uk/2014/10/10/men-with-big-feet-are-more-likely-to-cheat-hey-dont-shoot-the-messenger-guys-4900473/
Illicit Encounters on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illicit_Encounters

Comment: Define "loyal" / "faithful"... in a way that does **not** make polyamorous people keel over backwards with laughter. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar Keeping promises?

Comment: @gerrit: Good one. I just wonder how many of the sources that could be cited in this context have the same insight. ;-)

Comment: @devsol easy. Typical definition: If the partner knows/approves of having another partner, it's poly or open. If not, it's unfaithfulness.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a size translation table?  Hereabouts, the only people who'd wear size 40 shoes are clowns.

Comment: @jamesqf EU size probably? In that case size 40 is *quite* small for a man... it's like slightly less than average for a woman, typical dudes have sizes between 43 and 47. A (male) middle schooler could have 38-40.

Comment: @Bakuriu - the article's Russian, and i think Russia uses European size chart